# Does this sentence require a question mark at the end?

Tags: questions, question-mark

"Children are continuously forced to hear stereotypes about themselves because of their gender, but what if a child wanted to challenge their fate?"

I know it doesn't begin with a question word, but I was still curious if it could pass as a question.

Answer (score 0):

I would say yes. Here are some similar examples:
"Dogs are carnivores, but what if a dog wanted to eat kale?"
"Bears hibernate, but what if a bear chose to stay awake all winter?"

I'm struggling more with the reference to a singular child challenging "their" fate, but I understand this is commonly used now to avoid forcing a gender on to a child who may be agender, non-binary, transgender and so on.